# Create zip file without folder path

Tags: filenames, zip

I wrote a compressing command in Ubuntu. However,the zip file produced also contain path folder leading to the target file in form of folder. I only need the target file alone in the zip file. This is the code I currently using.

```
zip -9pr /mnt/test/Raimi/temp/Testing.zip /home/tect/Loco/*txt
```

where `mnt/test/Raimi/temp` is the destination folder `Testing.zip` is the output I intended to produced and `/home/tect/Loco` is the Original file located.

Please help pointed out a fault in my command if found.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about `cd /home/tect/Loco/ && zip -9pr /mnt/test/Raimi/temp/Testing.zip *txt`?

Comment: It shows  `bash: cd/home/tect/Loco/ : No such file or directory`

Comment: I see you got a working answer, but please learn to copy-paste or at the very least copy spaces properly.

Answer (score 8):

The `-j` (`--junk-paths`) option of `zip` is there exactly for this purpose.

From `man zip`:

> -j --junk-paths
>
> Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).

So, do:

```
zip -9jpr /mnt/test/Raimi/temp/Testing.zip /home/tect/Loco/*txt
```

Comment: And what if I want to run Cron task. For each time the cron activate,the produced output naming will increase by 1. Such as `Testing1`,`Testing2` an so on?

Comment: @mohdraimi:  That's a different question which basically implies running a script that saves a counter variable in another file.

Comment: Aren't the -j and -p flags inverse of one another, with -p being the default behavior?

Comment: This command removes also subdirectories!